# mkdir function in java

Tags: java, web-crawler, mkdir

I am trying to create a program that will download resources from a webpage into a file. I created an mkir function that creates a directory whose name is a hexadecimal version of the hash of a given String. I then, created a saveResource function that saves a resource in a file, as well as in a byte array. However, when I try saving the resource into the file I get an error message stating: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 648451a1 (Is a directory)

Here are the functions:

```
 public static File mkdir(String s) throws IOException
   {
      String dirname = s;
      s = Integer.toHexString(dirname.hashCode());
      File directory = new File(s);

      if  (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdir())
         throw new IOException("can't make directory for " + s);

      return directory;
   }

public static byte[] saveResource(File dir, String urlString, 
                      String argURLString)
      throws IOException, URISyntaxException
   {
      URL u = new URL(urlString);
      URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
      urlString = uc.getContentType();
      int contentLength = uc.getContentLength();

      try (InputStream raw = uc.getInputStream()) {
          InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(raw);

          byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
          int offset = 0;
          while (offset < contentLength) {
              int bytesRead = in.read(data, offset, data.length - offset);
              if (bytesRead == -1) break;
              offset += bytesRead;
      }
          if (offset != contentLength) {
              throw new IOException("Only read " + offset
                        + " bytes; Expected " + contentLength + " bytes");
          }
          urlString = u.getFile();
          urlString = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(dir)) {
              fout.write(data);
              fout.flush();
          }
          return data;

      }
      }
```

Comment: `FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(dir)` looks suspicious given the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simple and coming because you can't write data in directory.

Try to print `dir.isDirectory()` to confirm if it's directory. Since its part of argument, check the caller method.